# Android studio error: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:yogaDebugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: gradle

I tried multiple versions of AndroidStudio, and re-pulled the code to run, and finally reinstalled the windows 11 system, but still reported this error

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:yoga_testDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not determine artifacts for com.github.CymChad:BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper:3.0.4: Skipped due to earlier error



 * Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:yoga_testDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not determine artifacts for com.github.CymChad:BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper:3.0.4: Skipped due to earlier error
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:258)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:116)
...
```